# python subprocess Popen blocks parent process unexpectedly when calling by apache CGI

Tags: python, apache, subprocess, cgi

I have a python task (run.py) called by CGI script on Apache server 2.4.
I'm using python 2.7.11, operation system "Fedora release 23 (Twenty Three)"

in run.py I have

```
p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,"main.py"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
return "Your task has been launched"
```

I want to use Popen to start a non blocking process and get an instant return.

but problem is, it blocks the program. run.py will not return until main.py finished. anyone have any idea why Popen behaves different with what doc says?

I also tried

```
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,"main.py"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,"main.py"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,"main.py"],stdout=None,stderr=None)
```

all these above not working.

More info:

same code works as expected in my old apache server, version 2.2. 
is this issue has something to do with the apache server configuration file (httpd.conf)?

now what I can think up the the difference between new and old server are:

new server:

```
python 2.7.11, os Fedora release 23 (Twenty Three), new installed apache 2.4 (httpd.conf almost all default)
```

old server:

```
python 2.7.3, os Fedora release 17 (Beefy Miracle), apache 2.2 (httpd.conf have lots of lines then new server)
```

any clues? thanks alot

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention, in the new server I wrote the code in a test.py and call it using command line "python test.py". it works fine, got instant return and subprocess runs in background, there are definitely something interesting inside apache server...